# Stop Celery caching Django template

Tags: django, django-templates, celery

I have Django 3.24, celery 4.4.7 and celerybeat 2.2.0 setup via the RabbitMQ broker.

I have have a celery task that renders a Django template and then sends it to a number of email recipients.

The Django template is dynamic in as much as changes can be made to it's content at any time, which in turn rewrites the template. The trouble is that on occasions, I have to restart celery to get it to re-read the template.

My question is, is there any way of forcing celery to reread the template file, without requiring a full celery restart?

**celery.py**

```
    from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
    import os
    from celery import Celery

    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'backoffice.settings')

    app = Celery('backoffice')

    default_config = 'backoffice.celery_config'

    app.config_from_object(default_config)
    app.autodiscover_tasks()


    @app.task(bind=True)
    def debug_task(self):
        print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

**celery_config.py**

```
    from django.conf import settings
    broker_url = "amqp://someusername:somepassword@webserver:5672/backoffice"
    worker_send_task_event = False
    task_ignore_result = True
    task_time_limit = 60
    task_soft_time_limit = 50
    task_acks_late = True
    worker_prefetch_multiplier = 10
    worker_cancel_long_running_tasks_on_connection_loss = True
```

**celery command**

```
celery  -A backoffice worker -B -l info --without-heartbeat --without-gossip --without-mingle
```

Comment: I think You can use Watchdog to auto-reload celery worker.

Comment: Thanks Reza, but I want to try to avoid reloading Celery.